# Python decimal to binary giving random binary values

Tags: python, recursion, binary, decimal, converters

Im trying to write a code that can convert a decimal (int) into an binary number it works well with numbers like 10 but as soon as i try it with 100 or even with 14 sometimes it just outputs a completely random binary value.

```
binary = []
number = 10

def convert_binary(number):
    if number >= 1:
        convert_binary(number // 2)
        binary.append(number % 2)
        if len(binary) < 8:
            binary.insert(0, 0)
    if len(binary) == 8:
        print('===========================')
        print('Binärzahl:', *binary)
        print('===========================')

conver_binary(number)
```

Comment: Are you doing this as an exercise? I assume you're aware of the built-in `bin()` function.

Comment: Yes its an exercise and im also aware of bin. Still thanks a lot for the fast respond

Comment: Please fix the name error and show the wrong results.

Comment: No worries! I just wanted to make sure! :) Hard to tell what people already know or don't

Comment: If all your recursive calls do `binary.insert(0, 0)` then you'll insert a bunch of extra zeroes at the beginning of the array, and hit `len(binary) == 8` before you expect to.

Comment: @slothrop but if thats the case how would you fix it since i need to add the missing zeros before the print e.g. 10 is 1010 and i need to add 0000 before the print to have 00001010 as the end result

Comment: @IsItMe I think I would do it separately from the recursive function. Do it just once after the recursion completes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments i figured it out this is the code that worked for me!

```
# list for binary
binary = []

# func for decimal to binary conversion
def convert_binary(number):
    global binary
    if number >= 1:
        convert_binary(number // 2)
        binary.append(number % 2)

# func for adding zeros till 8-bit binary
def ins_zero():
    global binary
    flag = True
    while flag:
        if len(binary) < 8:
            binary.insert(0, 0)
        if len(binary) == 8:
            print('===========================')
            print('Binärzahl:', *binary)
            print('===========================\n')
            flag = False
```